# Do I need to call BindingOperations.DisableCollectionSynchronization?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` is a method suggested by many places to allow cross-thread changes on collection views, which normally is something you have to do per invoking into the UI thread.

Many places discuss `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` and say that afterwards you have to call `BindingOperations.DisableCollectionSynchronization`.

But what happens if I don't unregister the synchronization token? Is there a leak?

Comment: "*Many places ... say that afterwards you have to call BindingOperations.DisableCollectionSynchronization*" - who says that? Reading the documentation it seems clear that calling the method is optional. And when exactly would you call it? When your application terminates? It wouldn't matter at all then.

Comment: @Clemens: You are right, they don't say it explicitly and alos you are right when you terminate the application it doesn't matter. However, if you have to rebuild your view our during the application you open many views and close them again while the application is still running, the question is if there are leaks left.

Comment: Sounds like something you could simulate in a scratch app and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current implementation, the BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization method holds the collection by a weak reference. Therefore, its use will not create memory leaks.

Source code fragments used by the method:

```cs
        internal void Add(object collection, CollectionRecord cr)
        {
            base.Add(new WeakRefKey(collection), cr);
```

```cs
    internal struct WeakRefKey
    {
        internal WeakRefKey(object target)
        {
            _weakRef = new WeakReference(target);
            _hashCode = (target != null) ? target.GetHashCode() : 314159;
        }
```