# Can `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, thread-synchronization

I'm debugging a potential memory leak in a presentation model class used with WPF. It calls the [`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-data-bindingoperations-enablecollectionsynchronization(system-collections-ienumerable-system-object)) static method with an `ObservableCollection` property, which informs the WPF binding engine to use the given synchronization lock object when access the collection via data binding.

No where does this class call the `BindingOperations.DisableCollectionSynchronization`. Could this result in the associated collection being marked and preserved during garbage collection, even once the presentation model is finished with? Is it good practice to call `BindingOperations.DisableCollectionSynchronization` when a collection is finished with?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77011363/13349759